# Fixed div in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="container-fluid yellow">
    <div class="container blue">
        <div class="red"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.yellow {
    height: 160px; 
    background: yellow;
}
.blue { 
    height: 160px; 
    background: blue; 
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
.red { 
    height: 160px; 
    background: red; 
    position: fixed;
}
```

I am new to UI & bootstrap.

For "container" (blue) I gave `position: relative`.

When I give `position: fixed` to `div` 'red', it is moving aside instead of remaining in its place.

how to solve?

Comment: Please provide the HTML and CSS you've written, thanks!

Comment: What is "div x"?? Also, Please provide the HTML and CSS. Preferably in a codepen.io

Answer (score 0):

The main advantage to Bootstrap is the ability to flow divs for you that create a responsive website.  In general, you will not be setting the CSS position attribute, but rather let Bootstrap do that for you to flow the divs in a sane manner.

If you want to play and learn about the CSS position attribute, best not to do it within a bootstrap configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you make your `div` with class red, `fixed`, then you need do define the `width` of that div. For example add this to your code:

```
.red {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Here is the [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/qiriyej/1/edit?html,css,output) example. Let me know if you need something more.